# How to automatically enable provisioned extension in Edge?

Tags: powershell, browser-addons, microsoft-edge, unattended

I have created an unattended installation image of Windows 10 following [Kari’s excellent guide](https://win10.guru/windows-10-unattended-install-media-part-1-basics/). I have downloaded [uBlock Origin](https://www.microsoft.com/p/ublock-origin/9nblggh444l4) package from the Store and incorporated it with [Add-AppxProvisionedPackage](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/dism/add-appxprovisionedpackage) into the image.

After OS installation from the image created the add-on is provisioned to new users and available in Edge’s extensions menu. However, it is disabled by default. Is there a way to make it on by default instead?